# Terminology question about the correct term for areas of biological research

Tags: terminology, structure-prediction

I am writing a paper about DNA sequence prediction. DNA sequence prediction is done across various areas of biology, including, for example, RSS sequence prediction (in immunology) and prediction of promoter regions in vertebrate DNA sequences.

I was just wondering how one would describe such specific areas as "RSS sequence prediction" and "promoter region prediction". To be concrete, I wanted to write something like:

> This paper describes a method of DNA sequence prediction using
>   standard Bayesian modelling techniques. While there is much existing
>   work on DNA sequence prediction, most of this work is in the context
>   of biological research. Typically the techniques used are very
>   specific to the biological subdomain under consideration. Also, these
>   techniques often use use additional biological information about the
>   biological sequences under consideration, besides the sequence data
>   itself.

Is the term `subspeciality` the correct term to use here? Would `biological area` or `biological domain/subdomain` be better, or some other term?

Incidentally, if anyone knows other areas where DNA sequence prediction is used, please mention it/them. Thanks.

Comment: I would avoid using the term _sequence prediction_. You don't predict sequences, you identify them. Predicting would be giving me a likely RSS sequence for an organism you haven't analyzed and I doubt that is what you're doing. You may be predicting RSSs or genes or promoters but not _sequences_.

Comment: @terdon I see your point, but am unclear on how to reword my paragraph. Can you suggest an alternative phrasing for "DNA sequence prediction"? I can't make it more specific, because it is supposed to be a catch-all phrase for prediction of different kinds of DNA sequences, in different subdomains, i.e. RSS.

Comment: In this case, I would say _sequence identification_ or _RSS sequence prediction_ or _promoter prediction_. It is just the _sequence prediction_ I object to.

Comment: @terdon I think I'll go with "DNA sequence analysis" or possibly "Computational Analysis of DNA Sequences". These are used in various places. Is that OK with you?

Comment: Both sound fine to me, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

I think your suggestions are fine - there are a few ways you could write this.

I might use some variant of;

> The techniques used may be specific to the research question, and particular considerations may also be required depending on the accepted norms within the academic field

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Luke. I expanded my (proposed) paper quote a bit, to give better context.